# E0289 отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора "PERSON::PERSON", соответствующие списку аргументов main

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++builder, конструктор

Не могу никак понять в чем ошибка. Заранее благодарю

**Главная страница**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "PERSON.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int nPerson;
    cout << "How much Human you watn to created" << endl;
    cin >> nPerson;
    PERSON* human = new PERSON[nPerson];
    string name = "Volodia";
    string sex = "Man";
    PERSON tmp(name, sex, { 28, 07, 2003 });
    for (int i = 0; i < nPerson; i++) {
        tmp.printPerson(human[i]);
    }
}
```

*Person.h*

```
using namespace std;
#pragma once
class PERSON
{
private:
    string Pib;
    string sex;
    int bDay[3];
public:

    // Constructors
    PERSON();
    PERSON(string name);
    PERSON(string name, string sex);
    PERSON(string name, string sex, int* bday);
    PERSON(const PERSON& other);
    ~PERSON();
            // Input and Output
    PERSON input();
    void printPerson(PERSON& data);

};
```

**PERSON.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "PERSON.h"
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

// Constructors
PERSON::PERSON() {
    cout << "Created object without arguments!" << this << endl;
    Pib = sex = NAN;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        bDay[i] = 0;
    }
}

PERSON::PERSON(string name) {
    this->Pib = name;
}

PERSON::PERSON(string name, string sex) : PERSON(name) {
    his->sex = sex;
}

PERSON::PERSON(string name, string sex, int* bday) : PERSON(name, sex){
    cout << "You created a full Person!" << this << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        this->bDay[i] = bday[i];
    }
}

PERSON::PERSON(const PERSON& other) {
    cout << "Copy constructor!" << this << endl;
    this->Pib = other.Pib;
    this->sex = other.sex;                              
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        this->bDay[i] = other.bDay[i];
    }
}

PERSON::~PERSON() {
    cout << "Person deleted" << this << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{ 28, 07, 2003 }` - это никак не указатель на `int`.

Замените, например,

```
PERSON tmp(name, sex, { 28, 07, 2003 });
```

на

```
int tmp_array[] = { 28, 07, 2003 };
PERSON tmp(name, sex, tmp_array);
```

и смотрите следующие ошибки...

Comment: Ошибка идет от переменной name. По сути ошибка говорит что не конструктора для инициализации переменной name не существует

Comment: Вы попробуйте и скомпилируйте.  https://ideone.com/zN7OFy - убедитесь, что *компилируется*, но не линкуется - потому что нет `PERSON::printPerson(PERSON&)` - но именно это я и имел в виду под "смотрите следующие ошибки". А если вы знаете лучше, что у вас не так - начинаете нести пургу о переменной `name` - то, простите, зачем тогда спрашивать? Исправляйте сами, а мы у вас поучимся...